# Why does the sender message only appear when the recipient sends a message? (socketio) (nodejs) (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am developing a realtime chat in nodejs and react and socket io. In theory the chat is working, but the problem is that the sender's message only appears on the screen when the recipient sends a message too.

ex : I have browser 1 and browser 2. Every time browser 1 sends messages, these messages appear on its screen, but these messages only appear for browser 2 when browser 2 sends a message.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    }
});

dotenv.config();

const nameRoutes = require('./routes/nameRoutes');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use('/name', nameRoutes);

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ msg: 'API IS ALIVE!' });
})

let messages = []

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('send-message', (data) => {
        messages.push(data);
        socket.emit('message-from-server', messages);
        console.log(messages); 
    })
});

async function connection () {
    const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(uri);
        console.log('Connected to database');
        server.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

connection();

module.exports = app;
```

react/socketio

```
import * as C from './styles';

import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Chat = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:3010"));
  }, []);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('message-from-server', (data) => {
        setChatMessages(data); 
      })
    }
  }, [socket])

  const handleSendMessage = () => {
    if (message) {
      socket.emit('send-message', { message });
      setMessage('');  
    }
  }

  const handleExitChat = () => {
    navigate('/');
  }

  return (
    <C.Container>
        <C.MessagesChat>
          <h2>Messages</h2>
        </C.MessagesChat>
        {chatMessages.map(text => {
          return (
            <C.Messages>
              <p>{text.message}</p>
            </C.Messages>
          )
        })}
        <C.MessageText>
            <textarea 
              name="" 
              id="" 
              cols="30" 
              rows="10" 
              placeholder='Digite sua mensagem...'
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
            <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Enviar</button>
        </C.MessageText>
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

`socket.emit('message-from-server', messages);`

Try using `io.emit` instead, which broadcasts to all attached sockets. Socket.emit is used to send a message only to the called socket. In this case, that means the socket that first sent the message. This can be helpful for if you just want to notify that individual socket that something processed correctly, etc., but it isn't useful for when you want to notify other users of a socket's actitivies.

EDIT: Here's a link to the docs that describe your various emit options: https://socket.io/docs/v4/broadcasting-events/

Here's what your server-side code should look like:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // Define our routes first, but note the key new emit below this listener
    socket.on('send-message', (data) => {
        messages.push(data);
        // Notify all connected users each time a message is posted
        io.emit('message-from-server', messages);
        console.log(messages);
    }

    // THIS IS NEW
    // This is your initial load, to get the messages when you open the page.
    socket.emit('message-from-server', messages);

}
```

Note the difference between the `io.emit` that I use in the listener and the `socket.emit` that I use when first connecting.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But can you tell me why every time I refresh the page the previous messages only appear on the screen when I send a new message?

Comment: Yes, because you don't emit the messages when the user first connects. You need to have `socket.emit('message-from-server', messages)` outside of your `socket.on` language. As it is, you are only asking for the messages when you send them, not at any other time. If my answer works for you, please mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, you want your new `io.emit` to run after you receive a message, because you're going to push it out to all users. But you need `socket.emit` just inside of your initial socket connection so that you load your initial data right off the bat.

Comment: I bookmarked your answer, but could you show me how the code would look like this? Please

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my answer to show what I would do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187299/problem-sending-a-nick-in-my-messages-on-socket-io-through-localstorage

Comment: Could you help me with this issue? I can give you the best answer there too