# Problem sending a nick in my messages on socket io through localstorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm developing a real-time chat using socket, my main idea was to save the user's nickname in localStorage and take that nickname and send it to the server along with the message.

ReactJS

```
import * as C from './styles';

import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AuthContext from '../../context/AuthContext';

const Chat = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { showMyName } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:3010"));
  }, []);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('message-from-server', (data, name) => {
        setChatMessages(data); 
        console.log(name);
      })
    }
  }, [socket])

  
  const handleSendMessage = () => {
    const nick = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"))[0];
    setName(nick);
    if (message) { 
      socket.emit('send-message', { message, name });
      setMessage('');  
    } 
  }

  const handleExitChat = () => {
    navigate('/');
  }

  return (
    <C.Container>
        <C.MessagesChat>
          <h2>Messages</h2>
        </C.MessagesChat>
        {chatMessages.map(text => {
          return (
            <C.Messages>
              <p>{name}:  {text.message}</p>
            </C.Messages>
          )
        })}
        <C.MessageText>
            <textarea  
              name="" 
              id="" 
              cols="30" 
              rows="10" 
              placeholder='Digite sua mensagem...'
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
            <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Enviar</button>
        </C.MessageText>
        <C.Logout>
          <button onClick={handleExitChat}>Abandonar a conversa</button>
          <button onClick={handleExitChat}>Destruir a conversa</button>
        </C.Logout>
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default Chat;
```

ServerJs

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    }
});

dotenv.config();

const nameRoutes = require('./routes/nameRoutes');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use('/name', nameRoutes);

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ msg: 'API IS ALIVE!' });
})

let messages = []
let nick = ''

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('send-message', (data, name) => {
        messages.push(data);
        nick = name;
        io.emit('message-from-server', messages, nick);
    },
        socket.emit('message-from-server', messages, nick),
    )
});

async function connection () {
    const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(uri);
        console.log('Connected to database');
        server.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

connection();

module.exports = app;
```

When I open a browser this works, but when I open the second browser with another name in localStorage, my messages from browser 1 that I sent end up becoming messages with the name of browser 2 on that screen. Does anyone know what the best way to fix isos would be?

Comment: so every time some client sends a message, the server sends all the clients all the messages so far, plus the nick of the client who sent the latest message?

Comment: The server is doing exactly what you told it to do

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I would like to know how I could prevent this from happening.

Comment: You should tell the computer to do what you want it to do instead.

Comment: I want to know how my socket can store a localStorage name of the sender of the message in his message only

Comment: Sockets don't store that. Your program has to store it. Just like your program already stores the messages, it should also store the nicks, yes?

Comment: And how can my socket store two different nicknames from two browsers with this information coming from the socket?

Comment: How does your socket store two different messages from two browsers with this information coming from the socket?

Comment: So you can't help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same problem you were having with your other question. I really recommend you take some time to watch some socket.io tutorials and read the docs.

On your client you are sending `socket.emit('send-message', { message, name });` .

That means on the server side you are receiving an event `send-message` with `data === { message, name }`.

```
socket.on('send-message', (data) => {
    messages.push(data.message);
    nick = data.name;
    io.emit('message-from-server', messages, nick);
}
```

This is the way you would get it to do what you are expecting, but I really think you should read the docs so that you can get a grasp on these types of questions more easily.

Because at the end of this, with `io.emit('message-from-server', messages, nick);`, you're emitting the entire string of messages again, not just the most recent one, and you're including the user's nickname. It probably isn't going to work--really you need to restructure everything to emit only the most recent message after initial load (but that's another question).

Comment: So in io.emit shouldn't I send message and name together like this? Should it all be inside a single data like socket.on?

Comment: Would it be better instead of creating an array of messages and a variable name, I create a single object that receives name and image and export it through my socket? For example: chat = { name: null, message: null}?

Comment: I think sending message and name are fine. But the way you have it now, you're sending ALL messages along with the name. YOu instead only want to send the LAST message and the name. `io.emit('message-from-server', data.message, nick)`. And handle that on the front end.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('message-from-server', (data) => {
        setChatMessages(data.message); 
      })
    }
  }, [socket])

Comment: The frontend should look like this, right?

Comment: No, it will be more complicated than that. YOu'll need to figure out whether you are receiving a single message or multiple messages, and you'll need to append the single message to the list of messages. Look up the `...` operator and do some research on pushing an element onto an array in react state.

Comment: I highly recommend the net ninja's videos on socket.io. It's a little dated but really great and easy to follow, and it answers like all of your questions. Find him on youtube for free!

Comment: I confess that I didn't understand socket documentation very much and it's been hard to find good tutorials on youtube, but I'm really going to research this channel you indicated. Thanks

Comment: I'm really believing that maybe it's simpler to create a single object that stores messages and name in a single array, so I just return the array with the objects I want and display it on the screen

Comment: Exactly that, I managed to solve it by sending a dictionary with name and message and sending everything inside a single array.

Comment: Do you have knowledge of roms?